# How does frequency change with centripetal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, centripetal-force

Using the equation $$F_c = {{mv^2}\over{r}}$$ I can see that mass and velocity are directly proportional to centripetal force. I can also see that the radius length is inversely proportional to centripetal force.

Why when I look at the equation $$F_c = 4(\pi^2)(m)(r)(f^2)$$ do I see that radius is now directly proportional to centripetal force?

Also, does this make frequency directly proportional to centripetal force as well?

Answer (score 1):

First off, when two values are *directly proportional*, it not only means that they are related, but also that they are related by a constant of proportionality (i.e. as one changes, the other changes proportionally). For example, in your second equation, the centripetal force is directly proportional to the radial distance to the mass and proportional to the square of the frequency of the mass's orbit.

Second, when you rewrote the equation as $F_c = 4(\pi^2)(m)(r)(f^2)$, you may have left behind the meaning of the variables, and what *proportional* meant.

Yes, it is proportional to the radius of orbit. However, this is assuming you fix the mass of the object and the frequency of its orbit. This looks weird only because if you keep the same values fixed, but look at the first equation (same thing, different writing), the velocity that the mass $m$ has must also increase. This is because as you increase the radius, the mass has to travel a greater distance in the same amount of time, and so it must speed up.

Comment: Sorry, just one last question. Why is it that the radius is directly proportional in the second equation but inversely proportional in the first? Should it not remain consistent if the equations are indeed the same?

Comment: Because in the first equation you are forgetting that $v$ is also proportional to $r$. If you are talking about circular motion, $v=2\pi r f$

Answer (score 0):

Arturo's answer above is great, I just want to add mine because after working on understanding it, I think I have a simple explanation that might help someone. In the first equation listed in the original post, force and radius are inversely related if velocity and mass are held constant - this means that the frequency must change since velocity depends on radius (in order for v to remain constant while r is changing, the frequency must change). In the second equation, force and radius are directly proportional if mass and frequency are held constant. Both relationships are valid, depending on which variables are being held constant. Regarding the very last question - yes, this means that centripetal force and frequency are directly related (force is directly related to the square of frequency).

Answer (score 0):

$m \frac{v^2}{r} = Force$

$m \omega^2 r = Force$

$Force = ma$

$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$

$2 \pi f = \omega$

$f= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \omega$

From here you can make substitutions and arrive at the result. Let me know how it goes.